# no-unused-expressions: Expected an assignment or function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in full stack developing and I'm trying to code something to understand better frontend with React JS and Material UI. In this component, console give me this error at line 75( `this.props.isFriend(handle)`) but I do not understand what is wrong.

```
componentDidMount(){
    const {
      profile: { handle }
    } = this.props;
    
    this.props.isFriend(handle);
  }
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This line returns a value when it executes (probably a boolean), but it is not used, that's what the error message is telling you. You need to do something with the returned value.

Ex.

```
this.isFriend = this.props.isFriend(handle);
```

Comment: I've tried to assign the returned value to a var, but nothing changed

Comment: You have to use that var anywhere in your code, eg. as an `if` expression.

Comment: I've tried to use a global var but nothing changed, so I've tried to delete the lines that give me error but the error appeared on the same line even if the call is not here anymore. It's so strange